# Proper place to validate issuer for multi-tenant .Net Core Web API app

Tags: c#, single-page-application, asp.net-core-webapi, restful-authentication, msal.js

I'm developing a multi-tenant SPA application that calls a back-end .Net Core Web API for data.  The front end UI will use MSAL and Microsoft's v2 common endpoint for authenticating the user against AAD and obtaining an id and access token.

In my Web API, I want to validate the issuer, but as noted [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-convert-app-to-be-multi-tenant#update-your-code-to-handle-multiple-issuer-values), using the common endpoint provides metadata that makes the normal issuer validation un-useable.

I've seen references to a couple places where it may be possible to override or customize token validation, but I'm not sure which is preferred or if either of these methods causes undesired side effects.

One method uses the Events of the JwtBearer options: `options.Events.TokenValidated` and the other uses the `IssuerValidator` delegate of the TokenValidationParameters.

I don't want to have to write any token validation logic other than just ensuring the issuer exists in my database of verified issuers.  Should that logic go in the `IssuerValidator` or `TokenValidated`?

My current code looks like this (currently set up for single tenant)

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
   .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
       options.Authority = "https://myauthority.com";
       options.Audience = "https://myaudience.com/api/v1";
       options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
       {  
          ValidateIssuer = true,
          ValidIssuer = "myauthority.com",
          ValidateAudience = true,
          ValidAudience = "https://myaudience.com",
          ValidateLifetime = true,
          ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        };
    });
```

One of the issues I see with using `IssuerValidator` is that there does not appear to be a way to inject or pass in a reference to a dbContext needed to be able to look up a tenant id in a database.

Has anyone tackled this or done something similar?

Comment: Just had a read of this https://dzimchuk.net/enabling-multitenant-support-in-you-azure-ad-protected-applications seems helpful and points towards `IssuerValidator`. I understand the problem about getting a dbcontext injected into there and will be creating an answer when I can get near a computer

Comment: @matt_lethargic you mentioned posting an answer demonstrating how to get the dbcontext in `IssuerValidator`.  Is that still coming?  That feels the more natural place to perform my validation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check that in `OnTokenValidated` event , to access the database context , you can try :

```
 options.Events.OnTokenValidated = async (context) =>
   {


       var dbContext = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<BloggingContext>();
       var blogs = await dbContext.Blogs.ToListAsync();

       if (!true)
       {
           throw new SecurityTokenValidationException($"Tenant xxxxx is not registered");
       }

   };
```

Comment: I'm guessing in this scenario I would have to set `VaidateIssuer = false` in my `TokenValidationParameters` so that the token would pass initial validation?  Is that correct?

Comment: @RHarris . yes , set VaidateIssuer = false

Comment: I don't think it is correct (anymore?) to set ValidateIssuer = false.  in msal v3 with ValidateIssuer = true (and with a multi-tenant tenant like organizations) the default IssuerValidator will validate the general structure of the issuer contained in the token although any well formed issuer will get through.  So, while setting ValidateIssuer = true doesn't really achieve a whole lot, it isn't strictly true that you need to set ValidateIssuer to false.

Comment: Accessing the DB during the build step feels hacky and doesn't let you update the approved tenants without a restart.

Comment: @TomStyles wouldn't this access the db every time the OnTokenValidated event is fired during runtime meaning that you wouldn't have to restart the app?

Comment: @matt_lethargic - You are quite right. My mistake. It would fire on each event.

Answer (score 2):

Wow, so this lead me down a long road! As you pointed out most of the documents point towards setting `ValidateIssuer = false` and leaving at that. I tried the `IssuerValidator` and I didn't get anywhere. What I did find was `IAuthorizationHandler`. I've created a PoC Using IMyService in place of DBContext. I left `ValidateIssuer = false`.

```
public class IssuerAuthorizationHandler : IAuthorizationHandler
{
    private readonly IMyService _service;

    public IssuerAuthorizationHandler(IMyService service)
    {
        _service = service ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(service));
    }

    public Task HandleAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context)
    {
        if (context.User.FindFirst("iss") != null)
        {
            string issuer = context.User.FindFirst("iss").Issuer;
            // do issuer validation here
        }
        else
        {
            // fail the authentication
            context.Fail();
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Add this to DI

```
services.AddScoped<IAuthorizationHandler, IssuerAuthorizationHandler>();
```

Hope this help

**Update:**

Filter pipeline showing when authorisation handler is called

[image: core pipeline]

Comment: So you aren't using `IssuerValidation` in this scenario at all correct?

Comment: Incidentally, did you ever try `IssuerValidation` with `ValidateIssuer = true`?  My understanding is that it has to be set to true when using `IssuerValidation` or the delegate will never be called.

Comment: Correct it doesn't use the `IssuerValidator`, it could only be passed a method that again suffers the same problem. If you set `ValidateIssuer = false` then no, it does not use the `IssuerValidator` method

Comment: So when is the `IssuerAuthorizationHandler` being called?  If `ValidateIssuer` is false and the Authentication is not validating the issuer by default, what is using the new handler that you created?

Comment: Updated my answer, looks like it's called after the middleware is run

Comment: I based a solution on this but used a requirement and a policy to handle it. Seems closer to how it is "meant to work".

Answer (score 1):

I based my solution on matt_lethargic's answer, but I wanted to throw a specific response and have control of what happens rather than a blanket Authorization Failed redirect.

In `Program.cs` I add an **AuthorisationHandler** that will check the tenant and a **MiddlewareResultHandler** that will do the redirecting.

```
// Check for approved Tenant
builder.Services.AddScoped<IAuthorizationHandler, ApprovedTenantRequirementHandler>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IAuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler, ApprovedTenantAuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler>();
```

Also in `Program.cs` I set the default Policy to require an approved tenant.

```
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.DefaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .AddRequirements(new ApprovedTenantRequirement())
        .Build();
});
```

The requirement itself is very dull `ApprovedTenantRequirement.cs`

```
public class ApprovedTenantRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement
{
}
```

This is where we check the DB for the tenant ID `ApprovedTenantRequirementHandler.cs`

```
public class ApprovedTenantRequirementHandler : AuthorizationHandler<ApprovedTenantRequirement>
{
    private readonly ApplicationContext _applicationContext;

    public ApprovedTenantRequirementHandler(ApplicationContext applicationContext)
    {
        _applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    protected override async Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, ApprovedTenantRequirement requirement)
    {
        var validTenantIds = await _applicationContext.Tenants.Select(t => t.TenantIdGuid).ToListAsync();
        var tenantIdClaim = context.User.FindFirst(c => c.Type == "tid");

        if (tenantIdClaim is null)
        {
            return; // Requirement wasn't met - handle this later
        }

        if (validTenantIds.Contains(tenantIdClaim.Value))
        {
            context.Succeed(requirement); // Happy days
        }
    }
}
```

The middleware result handler takes the failed policy with the specific failed requirement and returns the 403. I'm building a api so I return some JSON with a message explaining what happened. The front end will expect this and show it to users. This means we can give a consistent user experience for authorization failures even if the reason they have failed varies.

```
public class ApprovedTenantAuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler : IAuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler
{
    private readonly AuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler defaultHandler = new();

    public async Task HandleAsync(
        RequestDelegate next,
        HttpContext context,
        AuthorizationPolicy policy,
        PolicyAuthorizationResult authorizeResult)
    {
        // If the authorization was forbidden and the resource had an approved tenant requirement,
        // provide a custom 403 response.
        if (authorizeResult.Forbidden && authorizeResult.AuthorizationFailure!.FailedRequirements
            .OfType<ApprovedTenantRequirement>().Any())
        {
            // Return a 403 and let them know why they have been denied.
            context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status403Forbidden;
            await context.Response.WriteAsJsonAsync(new {message = "Your organisation has not been approved to access this application;"});
            return;
        }

        // Fall back to the default implementation.
        await defaultHandler.HandleAsync(next, context, policy, authorizeResult);
    }
}
```