# TokenValidationParameters validation for multi-tenant ASP.NET Core Web API application

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-ad-msal, microsoft-identity-platform, microsoft-identity-web

This code is working for a single tenant application. How does it need to be changed to work with multi-tenant application (Web API)? Is setting `ValidateIssuer = false` the right way?

[sample](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/blob/main/samples/tab-personal-sso-quickstart/csharp_dotnetcore/Startup.cs#L37)

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
         {
             options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
         })
        .AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                var azureAdOptions = new AzureADOptions();
                Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", azureAdOptions);
                options.Authority = $"{azureAdOptions.Instance}{azureAdOptions.TenantId}/v2.0";
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        ValidAudiences = SSOAuthHelper.GetValidAudiences(Configuration),
                        ValidIssuers = SSOAuthHelper.GetValidIssuers(Configuration),
                        AudienceValidator = SSOAuthHelper.AudienceValidator
                    };
                });
```

Comment: [Does this post useful to you ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53989712/proper-place-to-validate-issuer-for-multi-tenant-net-core-web-api-app)

Comment: @Jason it is working for the single tenant application.